# Join query in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have written this query to display the last name, department number, and department name from all employees who work in toronto.

```
select last_name, job_id, department_id, department_name
from employees e
 join departments d on d.department_id=e.department_id
 join locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id and l.city='Toronto';
```

I am getting this error
 ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the first line to:

```
select e.last_name, e.job_id, e.department_id, d.department_name
```

Comment: Its working yahia. Thank you. So thus for my understanding. so if we are using multiple tables to retrieve there is always a need to use table aliases?

Comment: @user2186265 not necessarily BUT if any of the column names in those tables exist more than once you need to use aliases...

Comment: It would be a good practice to use table aliases whenever there is more than a single table involved. It's more robust and easier for future staff to work with the code.

Answer (score 2):

When a column exists on both tables participating in a join you need to prefix the column name with an alias to specify which column you would like.  In your join the `department_id` is shared by both tables, you can specify which column you would like using `d.department_id` in the selected columns list.

```
select 
  last_name, 
  job_id, 
  d.department_id, --specify which table you want this ambiguous column from
  department_name
from employees e
  join departments d 
  on d.department_id=e.department_id
  join locations l on 
  d.location_id=l.location_id and l.city='Toronto';
```

Answer (score 2):

use alias name to select the column from any particular table. For example, simply writing `department_id` will raise error, since it is available on multiple tables and it raise ambiguity error

So, better solution is select column with their alias name like

```
 select e.last_name, e.job_id, e.department_id, d.department_name
 from employees e
 join departments d on d.department_id=e.department_id
 join locations l on d.location_id=l.location_id and l.city='Toronto';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select last_name, job_id, department_id, department_name 
from employees 
join departments using(department_id) 
join locations using(location_id) where city='Toronto';
```